# Flip Counter Specific Start Date

Tags: javascript, html, date, counter, increment

I am trying to make a counter to start counting down from 5,000,000,000 from 1st of September to 13th of December.

I was able to make the counter to have increment of (-1) and I was able to change the number to 5 billion. However, I could not set a specific time for the function to start. I want counting down to start exactly at 5pm on 1st of September.

Click [here](https://bitbucket.org/cnanney/apple-style-flip-counter/src) for the code. (I have modified the index.html in my version, it is not very different so I am giving the original link)

Comment: Why don't you do a check if `new Date().getHours() == 17` and `getDate & getDay` to be for Sept 1 ?

Comment: Where should I add that code? Should I make it self-invoking? I am not very experienced with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "reset" your time to Sep 1.

Simply get the timestamp of December 13 (`1418428800` for 2014-12-13 at 00:00:00 UTC, calculate it with http://www.epochconverter.com if you need a different time or timezone) and in your page compute the difference in seconds and start the counter from that moment.

Example:

```
var endTime = 1418428800 // 2014-12-13 00:00:00 UTC

// The function that is run every second to update the displayed counter
function updateCounter() {
    var now = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000)
    var countdown = endTime - now
    // Display the value of countdown somewhere in the page
}
setInterval(updateCounter, 1000)
```